# Detect changes in input text (textarea)

Tags: jquery, textarea

I have a textarea in which users adds some text. 
After submitting the textarea, the user is presented with the text he or she has entered, but it is showing each word in a List.

```
<div id=0> "word0" </div>
<div id=1> "word1" </div>
```

Now this page also stores each of the words in an array:

```
WordArr[0] = word0;
WordArr[1] = word1;
...
```

Now the user can click on each word and the
WordArr for the clicked word becomes
`WordArr[0][0] = "clicked";`

Now this is all good. The user can now save the text in a mysql db using php. The database also store the original text without the div code.

BUT The user can also chose to edit the text. In this case I load the original text into a textarea, but this time i need to know if and what words the user deletes or if the user adds some words anywhere in the textarea. In short I need to keep track of which div's that has been changed. Or if anything has been added to the original textarea. So the user does not need to re-select words again.

Let's say the original text is:

> Hello there my jQuery friend. I'm happy today.

Then perhaps the user deletes or add something to this textarea:

> Hello there my friend. I'm quite happy today.

Then how would I get the changes to the original string entered, still keeping the divs which has been clicked?

Comment: This almost looks like you need to do a full blown *nix `diff` command but in javascript. There's some quick and dirty solutions but they are going to have caveats and possibly not find ALL changes.

Comment: I've tried this one http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/ but i cannot write anything in between the elements (words). So i guess i'm stuck. Have spent about twoo weeks on this problem :(

Answer (score 0):

I suggest maintaining an object with words for keys that keeps track of selected words. Then upon the entering of a space or the completion of editing, check which words are present. Upon click of a word call `handleWordClick(word)` and finally call `getFinal()` to get an array of objects like this `{word: "apple", clicked: true}`.

```
var words = [],
    clicks = {};

var checkWords = function() {    
     words = $(this).val().split(" ");
     $("#out").val(words.join(","));
};
//call this from whatever event a word click triggers
var handleWordClick = function(word) {
    clicks[word] = true;    
};
//to get all of your data, run this
var getFinal = function() {
    return words.map(function(word) {
        return {
            word: word,
            clicked: clicks[word]
        };
    });
}

$("#in").keydown(function(event) {
    //once they enter space, check what the words are
    if( event.keyCode == 32 ) {
        checkWords.call(this);
    }        
})
//when they're done editing, check what the words are
$("#in").blur(checkWords)
​
```

Comment: Would this work? If I have "I am quite (clicked) happy (clicked). " and the changing it to "He was very happy (clicked). And he jumped into the air". ?

Comment: Note that this is not bulletproof; e.g. in case `WordArr` contains a word twice and one has been deleted, the `diff` function won't notice.

Comment: @MadsChristianSidenius I don't understand why you need to see what changed rather than just automating the whole process of selecting words. Post more code and I'm sure there is a better way.

Comment: Is it possible to have jquery add each word typed into a textarea to an array. Live as they type?

Comment: Any ways to add words to an array LIVE as you write them? and remove them as you delete them?

So if I enter:

He is a very happy man

a script would detect this and LIVE create an array containing:
liveArr = ['He','is','a','very','happy','man'] ???

The I could create another array detecting which of the words in the array, that has been clicked?

clickArr = ['','','clicked','','','']

And then deleting this sentence, will automatically remove the clickArr, leaving it empty?

Any way to detect words LIVE?

Comment: Here is a fiddle with live checking of words and a means of maintaining clicked words. The final response will have an object of all words with whether they were clicked or not. http://jsfiddle.net/wrKdg/1/